# Confused with input configuration type of an MCU

Tags: microcontroller, gpio

Following is an input with pull-up configuration:

[image]

And below is an input with pull-down configuration:

[image]

But for [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/cd00171190-stm32f101xx-stm32f102xx-stm32f103xx-stm32f105xx-and-stm32f107xx-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) MCU the following register is given as GPIO input options:

[image]

But this is confusing to me. An input pin is either pull-up or pull-down input. What's meant here by "Input with pull-up / pull-down"? How can an input be both? Am I interpreting something wrong?

Comment: That programme how you gonna use input. Probably it means the use of internal resistor. You can find more detailed information on microcontrollers datasheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't both at the same time.

Notice that it says "Refer to Table 20: Port bit configuration table". If you follow that link you'll see a table that explains the overall configuration.

[image: Table 20. Port bit configuration table. Taken from page 161 of the datasheet.]

This table describes the behaviour for a particular port. When the `MODE[1:0]` register for the I/O pin is set to 0b00, it is placed into input mode. Additional registers then configure the exact behaviour of the input pin.

When `CNF[1:0]` is set to 0b00, the I/O pin is configured in analog mode. This is described in section 9.1.10 of the datasheet.

When `CNF[1:0]` is set to 0b01, the I/O pin is configured in input floating mode. In this configuration the pin is connected directly to the input driver's Schmitt trigger.

When `CNF[1:0]` is set to 0b10, the I/O pin is configured in input pull-up/pull-down mode.

You can see this pull-down/pull-up selection behaviour in Figure 15 (section 9.1.7):

[image: Input configuration block diagram. The I/O pin is connected to the input driver's Schmitt trigger, and optional pull-up and pull-down resistors can be switched on depending on the configuration registers.]

If you look at the final column of Table 20, it shows that input pull-down mode is selected by setting the `PxODR` register to 0, and pull-up mode is selected by setting the `PxODR` register to 1. When pull-down mode is selected, the STM32 internally connects the GPIO pin to Vss (GND) with a resistor. When pull-up mode is selected, the STM32 internally connects the GPIO pin to Vdd with a resistor. When input floating mode is selected, the STM32 disconnects both of the resistors and leaves the input in high-impedance (Hi-Z) input mode. It never connects both resistors at once.

The datasheet doesn't explain this use of `PxODR` very well, but what it means is the I/O pin's corresponding bit in the output data register, i.e. `GPIOx_ODR[n]` for the `n`'th pin in GPIO port `x`, is repurposed to specify the pull-down or pull-up state when `MODE[1:0]` is 0b00 (input mode) and `CNF[1:0]` is 0b10 (pull-down/pull-up mode).

This functionality is useful because it saves you adding a separate resistor to your design to pull the IO pin to a defined state when the input is left floating (Hi-Z). Since it's configurable at runtime, you can also change the input to high-Z, pull-down, or pull-up on the fly if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The MCU has internal pull-up and pull-down. It does not mean they are enabled simultaneously in that mode, it just means one of them is enabled, compared to the mode where neither is enabled.